# Using a variable as table name fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, execute

Why does this fail with the following error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'reporting_rawdata_v2'.

the name of the table is "dbo.reporting_rawdata_v2" but either with/without "dbo" it still fails...

```
Use reporting2 
Go

Declare @Backupdate varchar(25), @sql NVARCHAR(max)
Set @Backupdate = REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SYSDATETIME(), 100) as varchar),' ','_'),':', '')
Select @Backupdate

SET @sql = 'Select * Into reporting_rawdata_BACKUP_' + @Backupdate + 'From reporting_rawdata_v2';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: Is it working without the "Into" ?

Comment: try adding a space between at the start of the last string, before 'from' ?

Comment: change your exec to a Print to see what the actual sql is...should be straight forward to fix after that

Comment: Some tags missing, for example dbms.

Comment: There is no space between your dynamically named table and the "From" so yeah fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No space between dynamically named table and `From`

```
SET @sql = 'Select * Into reporting_rawdata_BACKUP_' + @Backupdate + ' From reporting_rawdata_v2';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: The more I read the more I think I was on the wrong track, and this is much simpler and more obvious.  I've upvoted this answer and removed mine.